# update xml inside a root node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I cant seem to get my xml to generate inside the  node.   it repeats the entire xml structure every time.  the use case is that this file will be repeatedly updated over hours/days.   this xml file also connects to a backend so it's critical that i keep it in this format.

currently the xml ends up looking like this:

```
<xmlcontainer>
  <details>
    <name>name</name>
    <phone>phone</phone>
    <email>email</email>
    <image>0</image>
    <image>1</image>
  </details>
</xmlcontainer><xmlcontainer>
  <details>
    <name>name2</name>
    <phone>phone2</phone>
    <email>email2</email>
    <image>3</image>
    <image>4</image>
  </details>
</xmlcontainer>
```

when it should look like this.

```
<xmlcontainer>
  <details>
    <name>name</name>
    <phone>phone</phone>
    <email>email</email>
    <image>0</image>
    <image>1</image>
  </details>
  <details>
    <name>name2</name>
    <phone>phone2</phone>
    <email>email2</email>
    <image>3</image>
    <image>4</image>
  </details>
</xmlcontainer>
```

below is my code, spanning across 2 frames.   what am i missing that's making this happen?
i messed with fs.open(fl2,FileMode.APPEND); and fs.open(fl2,FileMode.WRITE); but it doesnt appear to make any big difference.

thanks

```
//frame 2
var xml_file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('app/information.xml').nativePath;

    var xml_created = false;
    var xml_data = "";

    function load_xml(f_name){
      var target_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(f_name);
      var target_load:URLLoader= new URLLoader();
      var xmlData : XML = new XML();
      target_load.load(target_url);
      target_load.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, target_complete);
      target_load.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, target_error);

      function target_complete (evt:Event):void {
        xmlData = new XML(evt.target.data);
        xml_created = true;
        xml_data = String(xmlData.details);
        nextFrame();
        trace("OK - load XML")
      }

      function target_error(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
        nextFrame();
        trace("ERROR - load xml - check xml file name");
      }

    }

    load_xml(xml_file);

//frame 5
function saveFiles_fun (){
  var xmlData:XML = new XML(<xmlcontainer>
  </xmlcontainer>
  );

  var details:XML = new XML(<details/>)
  //client.appendChild(<id/>);
  details.appendChild( new XML( "<name>qwe</name>" ));
  details.appendChild( new XML( "<phone>qwe</phone>" ));
  details.appendChild( new XML( "<email>qwe</email>" ));

  for (var fna:int = 0; fna<fileNameArray.length; fna++) {
    details.appendChild( new XML( "<image>" + fna + "</image>" ));
  }

  xmlData.appendChild(details);

  var fl1:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(xml_file);
  var fl2:File = new File( fl1.nativePath );

  var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
  try{
    fs.open(fl2,FileMode.APPEND);
    fs.writeUTFBytes(xmlData);
    fs.close();
    doSomething();
  }catch(e:Error){}
}


function doSomething(){
 form.alert.text = alert4;
 var _tim5 = setTimeout(gotoAndPlay, 1000,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your issue is with this line.

```
fs.open(fl2,FileMode.APPEND);
```

Why are you not just recreating the file completely and then writing it over the existing file?

```
FileMode.APPEND
```

> Specifies that the file is open for appending. The file is created if
>   it does not exist. If the file exists, existing data is not
>   overwritten, and all writing begins at the end of the file.

What you need to use is

> FileMode.WRITE

You also should not nest your functions this will cause issues for you if you make it a common practice.

[UPDATE]

```
// in the code you supplied find this line
xmlData.appendChild(details);

// and right above it add this line
xmlData.appendChild(xml_data);

// so the resulting code will look like this
xmlData.appendChild(xml_data); // xml_data is where the original document is stored
xmlData.appendChild(details);

// also include the change to 
fs.open(fl2,FileMode.WRITE);
```

Comment: I hope you did not pay top dollar for this code. It is not clean code at all.

Comment: i do not want to get into that.  this whole thing is a sore spot.

Comment: Well try changing APPEND to WRITE and see what you get.

Comment: WRITE just overwrites the entire document. it doesnt 'add' anything.

Comment: That's my point. You have to rebuild the entire document in action script then write it out to the file in one shot.

Comment: I added an UPDATE to my answer give it a shot.

Comment: it appears to be just overwriting the previous content in <details>

Comment: user1004277: If you want to get tricky or your file is really large, you can open it for writing, find string </xmlcontainer>, replace it with new <detail/> block and close </xmlcontainer>. But if file is less than hundred megs, it probably doesn't worth it.

Comment: the file will be fairly small. i'd be surprised if it hit over a meg. but i still cannot get the above functioning

Comment: currently with the above changes it will populate an empty <xmlcontainer> parent node. but afterwards it replaces the content within <xmlcontainer> on each write.  so there is never more then 1 <details> node

Answer (score 0):

From where your "saveFiles_fun" method is getting called? I guess you are creating a new instance of XML using this code snippet

var xmlData:XML = new XML(
  );

and then you are adding the childXML.